# Put existing virtualenv projects into virtualwrapper

Tags: virtualenv

Let's say that I have already created a virtualenv project by `virtualenv venv`. What is the best way to add this project to virtualwrapper? The way I can think of is creating a virtualwrapper folder, figuring out package dependencies, put the virtualenv project directory into virtualwrapper folder, and then install necessary packages. Is possible to avoid this tedious process?

Answer (score 0):

No, virtualenvs are not portable, you cannot move existing virtualenv to `$HOME/.virtualenvs` where virtualwrapper stores it virtualenvs. Recreating is the only way.

There is one thing you can simplify — list installed projects with their versions and reinstall exactly that versions:

```
# In the venv
pip freeze > requirements.txt
deactivate

# Activate a new virtualwrapper-managed venv
workon newenv
pip install -r requirements.txt
```